# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL nodes

Tags: javascript, node.js, localhost

I'm trying to start a localhost server via nodejs and mySql database.
I'm getting an error which says:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at /Users/Liran/Desktop/nodejs/server.js:34:13
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object. (/Users/Liran/Desktop/nodejs/server.js:32:7)
```

this error is caused by running the following javascript code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql')
var fs = require('fs'),
path = require('path');

var ipaddress = '127.0.0.1';
var port = 8080;

// ----------- MySQL Connection ------
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '1',
});
connection.connect();


// --------- Set upload directory  -------

app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.bodyParser({ keepExtensions: true, uploadDir: '../public/images/' }));

});
app.fs = fs;

// ------------ ROUTES  ---------------
var RouteDir = 'routes',
files = fs.readdirSync(RouteDir);

files.forEach(function (file) {
    var filePath = path.resolve('./', RouteDir, file),
    route = require(filePath);
    route.init(app, connection);
});



// ----------- Run Server ----------------
app.listen(port, ipaddress, function() 
{
    console.log('%s: Node server started on %s:%d ...',
                Date(Date.now() ), ipaddress, port);
});`enter code here`
```

basically all I'm doing is to set the server ip & port and connect it to the mysql db.. please tell me what am I doing wrong and why is that error appears? and if there are any code changes that I should make in order to make a good localhost server via nodejs and mysql please let me know :)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks to me like RouteDir isn't an array. Likely the path is invalid. Maybe try using `__dirname + "/routes"` instead?

Comment: actually I don't think there is any problem with the path. there is a folder named routes which is in the same folder with the file which contains the code above.

Comment: Just because the foldering this doesn't mean FS is picking it up properly. Try logging it to see

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm pretty much a beginner in java script and node. can you please specify more about what should I do in order to fix that problem? how can I check which path should I specify in order to get to the routes folder. thank you

Comment: `console.log(files);`

Comment: when I use console.log(files) it prints the all of the 'routes' folder contents (which all of the files there are .js files) in addition to one '.DS_STORE' file. any idea what that means?

Comment: That's an OSX system file. Try adding a conditional inside the forEach: `if(path.extname(files[i]) === ".js")`

Comment: Is "\`enter code here\`" really at the end of your source file or did that get appended when you pasted the code here somehow?

Answer (score 2):

One of the files you are `require()`ing in your `files.forEach()` callback has an illegal token. You may want to insert a debug statement before the `require()` so you can determine which file is having the problem. From there, you can use a linter like `jshint` to find the exact location of the illegal token in that file.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer I don't know if I understood you correctly so I removed all of the files in the folder routes which is the specified folder in the path for the files. even when I removed all of the files (which allegedly should cause the for each would not be performed even once) I'm still getting the same error. please let me know if I misunderstood you and what I should do next in order to fix that. thanks

Comment: Is your `forEach()` executing after removing the files?

Comment: Hi, I checked it out right now and the foreach() is not executing whether there are files in 'routes' directory or it's empty. after the foreach line is executed the program fails in both cases. thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your code

`// ----------- MySQL Connection ------
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '1',
});
connection.connect();`

you have an extra coma next to the password.

Thats the only actual error I see